I want to reuse GUI code instead of making multiple copies, but GUI is not showing text properly
I want to reuse GUI code instead of making multiple copies (code redundancy), but the problem is that when I press 1 it shows First,  but when I press 2 it still shows First instead of Second.
This code below doesn't work properly:
Gui, status_GUI:-Caption +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, status_GUI:Color, Black
Gui, status_GUI:Font, s13 cWhite

1::
    Hide_active_GUI()
    ;-------------- GUI start
    Gui, status_GUI:Add, Text,, First
    Gui, status_GUI:Show, x900 y850 NoActivate
    SetTimer, Hide_active_GUI, 500
    ;-------------- end GUI
Return

2::
    Hide_active_GUI()
    ;-------------- GUI start
    Gui, status_GUI:Add, Text,, Second
    Gui, status_GUI:Show, x900 y900 NoActivate
    SetTimer, Hide_active_GUI, 500
    ;-------------- end GUI
Return

Hide_active_GUI() {
    Gui, status_GUI:Hide
    return
}

Code below works perfectly fine, but the big problem is code redundancy:
1::
    Hide_first_GUI()
    
    ;-------------- GUI start
    Gui, first_GUI:-Caption +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop
    Gui, first_GUI:Color, Black
    Gui, first_GUI:Font, s13 cWhite

    Gui, first_GUI:Add, Text,, First
    Gui, first_GUI:Show, x900 y850 NoActivate
    SetTimer, Hide_first_GUI, 500
    ;-------------- end GUI
Return

2::
    Hide_second_GUI()

    ;-------------- GUI start
    Gui, second_GUI:-Caption +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop
    Gui, second_GUI:Color, Black
    Gui, second_GUI:Font, s13 cWhite

    Gui, second_GUI:Add, Text,, Second
    Gui, second_GUI:Show, x900 y900 NoActivate
    SetTimer, Hide_second_GUI, 500
    ;-------------- end GUI
Return

Hide_first_GUI() {
    Gui, first_GUI:Hide
    return
}

Hide_second_GUI() {
    Gui, second_GUI:Hide
    return
}


it looks like you have only one GUI, not two

If you want to reuse a GUI:

move the control addition instruction (Add, Text) outside of keybindings
assign a ContolID to it with the v parameter, e.g.:

Gui, status_GUI:Add, Text, vIndex, First


change the text in keybindings using GuiControl:

GuiControl, Text, Index, Second

